# Is there a limit on the number of methods you can add to an object. If there isn't, how do you prioritise the methods?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

```
<p>hi</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hi</p>
<script>
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
  arr[x].innerHTML = "Hi there";
}
</script>


<p>hi</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hi</p>
<script>
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
for (var x = 0; x < arr; x++) {
  arr[x].innerHTML = "Hi there";
}
</script>
```

Why doesnt the second method work?
Is there a limit on the number of methods you can add on a single object?If there isn't, how do you prioritise the methods?

Comment: In the second one, `arr` is a integer and not an Array.

Comment: `arr.` ?!?! And in your second code, `arr` is a number that has no properties.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `for (var x = 0; x < arr; x++) ` . 'arr' is already a number, the length

Comment: What do you mean by "*prioritise the methods?*" I don't see any methods in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the typo everyone. even though i have erased the full stop, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

in second :

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
```

this length of elements...

and:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.; x++)
```

`arr.;`???

Change like first example and all works fine..

Comment: sorry for the typo. even though ive edited it, there is still an error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit for the number of methods, therefor, you are setting the property text of a tag, not adding properties to it.
Even further:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.; x++)
```

You probably nedded :

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.lenght; x++)
```